# What do I use the Serializer create method for?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a simple flow where the a user POSTs a secret code to an api endpoint. By doing so the user creates a foreign key relationship with another model.

I achieved the desired behaviour on the serializer by overwriting the create method like so:

```
class RegisterUserToCustomerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    company_code = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data['user']
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(company_code=validated_data['company_code'])
         except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=404)
         user.related_customer = customer
         user.save()
         return customer
```

In normal Django I would have implemented the behaviour on the forms `save(commit=False)` method. Since DRF does not have this function I feel stuck with the `create()` and `update()`.

Two things really bug me about my solution:

1. I have to return the customer from create method eventhough the user was edited. But since the 'company_code' variable does not exist on the user DRF will through an error if I return the user
2. I am overwriting the `create()` method but I am not really creating anything. Sure, I could use update but in terms of design, this makes it even worse I fear. **Everything about using the `create()` method feels weird about this.** From accessing the user to the return statement.

Do you guys see ways to avoid this?

Comment: Please note that this is not a ModelSerializer

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't feel like a job for a serializer at all. Note that you are using a plain serializer, which doesn't usually have create or update methods at all; there is no reason to create them here.

You should do this in the view.